# Not able to call a shell script from an ansible playbook

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, sage

I am trying to run two shell scripts in background through ansible playbook.
The playbook is running successfully and the displaying that all the tasks ran successfully.

But these two shell scripts are not running. 
I have checked this with:

```
ps -ef | grep sh
```

These two shell scripts are required to run a sage service and I am trying to automate the s
age server configuration using ansible.
Here is how the playbook looks like :

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
   - name : update system
     shell : apt-get update

   - name : install dependencies
     shell : apt-get install -y m4 build-essential gcc gfortran libssl-dev

   - name : install python-software-properties
     shell : apt-get install python-software-properties

   - name : add sage ppa repo
     shell : apt-add-repository ppa:aims/sagemath

   - name : update system
     shell : apt-get update

   - name : install dvipng
     shell : apt-get install dvipng

   - name : install sage binary
     shell : apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary

   - name : run create sage script
     shell : . ./create_sagenb &

   - name : run start sage script
     shell : . ./start_sage &
```

This is how create_sagenb looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Creating Sage notebook
screen -S "Sage_Server" sage -c 'notebook(interface="",directory="/root/.sage/sage_notebook.sagenb",port=80,accounts=true)'
```

This is how start_sage looks:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Creating Sage notebook
address=$(hostname --ip-address)
screen -S "Sage_Server" sage -c "notebook(interface=" "'$address'" ",port=80,accounts=true)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I successfully invoke screen sessions in Ansible:

```
- name: Invoke script
  command: /usr/bin/screen -d -m sudo -u myuser /usr/local/bin/myuser.sh -i -y
```

This starts a screen session in detached mode (-d and -m combined), which I then use sudo to switch to a specific user to run my script as.

Comment: This is also how you would do it nested within another script, or from cron.

Answer (score 1):

When you log out - or in this case Ansible finishes its tasks and closes the ssh connection, an exit signal will be automatically sent to all child processes. Since screen was not detached I guess it as well will terminate on logout. It's like you're typing "exit", not simply disconnecting.

You should be able to prevent this with `nohup`, e.g.:

```
- name : run create sage script
  shell : nohup ./create_sagenb &
```

`nohup` and `screen` are a bit redundant here and maybe you can remove `screen` if you do not want to re-attach to the session `Sage_Server` later.

But I think you should look into creating an init script instead, for example with `start-stop-daemon`. Have a look at this: https://www.project-insanity.org/blog/2012/09/27/install-sage-5-3-on-debian-squeeze-initscript/

Comment: I have tried running it in background, nohup and disown. Nothing seems to work. This script does not end.It holds the terminal for itself and hence no command is working

Comment: @apurv, use `supervisor` or something to keep it running. using `nohup` and other things like `screen` are hacky.